# Finding unique partitions for a number

Tags: unique

I am using below code for finding partitions for a given number (N). How can I ensure only unique partitions? For instance partitions (1, 1, 1, 7), (1, 1, 7, 1), (1, 7, 1, 1) and (7, 1, 1, 1) would be considered the same and only one of these should be output.

Thanks

Regards

```
 Dim N = 10

        For i As Integer = 0 To N
            For j As Integer = 0 To N
                For k As Integer = 0 To N
                    For l As Integer = 0 To N
                        If i + j + k + l = N Then
                            Dim St As String = String.Format("({0:d}, {1:d}, {2:d}, {3:d})", i, j, k, l)
                            Console.WriteLine(St)
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next

        Console.Read()
```

EDIT: Below seems to be working from someone's suggestion;

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer.")
        Dim sReadLine As String = Console.ReadLine()
        Dim iValue As Integer

        If IsNumeric(sReadLine) Then
            iValue = CInt(sReadLine)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("'" & sReadLine & "' is not a numeric value. Press any key to exit.")
            'Application.Exit()
            Console.Read()
            Exit Sub
            End
        End If

        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("Number is {0}", iValue)
        Console.WriteLine("")

        Partitions1(iValue)

        Exit Sub

    End Sub

    Dim partitions As New List(Of Part)

    Private Sub Partitions1(N As Integer)
        For i As Integer = 0 To N
            For j As Integer = 0 To N
                For k As Integer = 0 To N
                    For l As Integer = 0 To N
                        If i + j + k + l = N Then
                            Dim thisPartition As New Part()
                            thisPartition.Parts = New Integer() {i, j, k, l}
                            If Not partitions.Contains(thisPartition) Then
                                partitions.Add(thisPartition)
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next

        For Each x In partitions
            Dim St = "("
            For Each y In x.Parts
                St = St & y & ", "
            Next
            St = Left(St, Len(St) - 2)
            St = St & ")"
            Console.WriteLine(St)
        Next

        Console.WriteLine("")
        Console.WriteLine("{0} unique partititons found.", partitions.Count)
        Console.Read()

    End Sub

    Public Class Part 'Sorted array of integer with comparer
        Implements IEquatable(Of Part)
        Public Property Parts As Integer()
            Get
                Return m_Parts
            End Get
            Set(value As Integer())
                m_Parts = value
                Array.Sort(m_Parts)
            End Set
        End Property

        Private m_Parts As Integer()

        Public Overloads Function Equals(other As Part) As Boolean _
           Implements IEquatable(Of Part).Equals
            If other Is Nothing Then
                Return False
            End If
            If other.Parts.GetLength(0) <> m_Parts.GetLength(0) Then Return False
            Dim result As Boolean = True
            Array.Sort(other.Parts)
            For I As Integer = 0 To other.Parts.GetLength(0) - 1
                If other.Parts(I) <> m_Parts(I) Then
                    result = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            Return result
        End Function
        ' Should also override == and != operators.
    End Class

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

Collect the found solutions in a list, then writen an algo which eliminates the duplicates from the list and then print the list.